# Big trouble. And Vk Api Again

Tags: c#, arrays, json, api, vk

Before everything was fine. I could deserialize any JSON. But now I have meet json, which makes me crazy. I'm trying to get user songs. So now I need you help. 
 this is my JSON : (sorry for json)(slashes before some urls because I haven't got much reputation)

```
response: {

count: 529,
items: [{

id: '34',
photo: 'http://cs617119.v...7/jlKfbdpqdnI.jpg',
name: 'Татьяна Плуталова',
name_gen: 'Татьяны'
}, {

id: 326503650,
owner_id: 34,
artist: 'Ocean Jet',
title: 'Distant',
duration: 229,
url: 'http://cs1-50v4.v...ETD5kMP2-rzbQLisQ',
lyrics_id: 134538662,
genre_id: 17
}, {

id: 321364793,
owner_id: 34,
artist: 'Aaron Embry',
title: 'The Raven's Song',
duration: 145,
url: 'http://cs1-35v4.v...GRtlpummhArtvlRPg',
genre_id: 9
}, {

id: 318936948,
owner_id: 34,
artist: 'The Smiths',
title: 'How Soon Is Now',
duration: 233,
url: 'http://cs1-45v4.v...8Bqm9Z_ja-S43xffw',
genre_id: 9
}]}
```

this is my deserializion class

```
public class SongData2
{

[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "items")]
    public List<SongMaders> songs { get; set; }

    public class SongMaders
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "artist")]
        public string Artist { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "title")]
        public string SongName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "url")]
        public string SongUri { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "dutation")]
        public int Duration { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "owner_id")]
        public int OwnerId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "lyrics_id")]
        public int LyricsId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "genre_id")]
        public int GenreId { get; set; }
    }
```

and I need to get the user's properties, before I got some custom classes and they won't work too. User properties - it's where was name, photo etc. 
This is my deserialize code :

```
private void Page1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient AudioWC = new WebClient();
        AudioWC.DownloadStringCompleted += AudioWC_DownloadStringCompleted;
        AudioWC.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(uri));
    }

    private void AudioWC_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
           try
        {

            JObject jobject = JObject.Parse(e.Result);
            JArray array = (JArray)jobject["response"]["items"];
            MessageBox.Show(array.ToString());
            var answer = (SongData2)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SongData2>(e.Result);
            foreach (SongData2.SongMaders songs in answer.songs)
            {
                SongData.SongMaders usersongs = new SongData.SongMaders();
                usersongs.Artist = songs.Artist;
                usersongs.Duration = songs.Duration;
                usersongs.SongUri = songs.SongUri;
                usersongs.Id = songs.Id;
                usersongs.SongName = songs.SongName;
                usersongscollforbinding.Add(usersongs);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            this.SpinningAnimation.Stop();
            this.AnimEllipse.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        UserSongsList.ItemsSource = usersongscollforbinding;

    }
```

I hope you will help me. You my last hope.

Comment: Your json is both [nonstandard](http://json.org/) and broken.  Nonstandard because 1) strings are single-quoted rather than double-quoted, and 2) property names are not quoted.  Luckily Json.NET can handle this anyway.  Broken because 3) the entire string needs to be surrounded by `{` and `}`, and 4) the embedded quote in `'The Raven's Song'` needs to be escaped to `'The Raven\u0027s Song'`.  3) is easily fixable; 4) is tricky.  Is this your real Json or did you make a copy/paste error?

Comment: Also, the first entry in your json appears to be an artist, not an album.  Can you confirm?  Do you know the data model for an artist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems here:

1. Your json lacks outer braces.  If this is not a copy/paste error, you will need to fix this somehow, for instance by replacing `JObject.Parse()` with:

   ```
   public static JObject ParseWithMissingBraces(string json)
   {
       return JObject.Parse(AddMissingOuterBraces(json));
   }

   public static string AddMissingOuterBraces(string json)
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < json.Length; i++)
       {
           if (char.IsWhiteSpace(json[i])
               || json[i] == '\t'
               || json[i] == '\r'
               || json[i] == '\n'
               || json[i] == '\0')
               continue;

           if (json[i] == '['
               || json[i] == '{')
               return json;
           return string.Format("{{{0}}}", json);
       }
       return json;
   }
   ```
2. The string literal `'The Raven's Song'` contains an embedded quote that is not escaped.  This looks to be a bug in the system that generated the json.  It should be either `'The Raven\u0027s Song'` or `"The Raven's Song"`  This may have happened because the json was created with strings surrounded by single quotes (`'`) while the [json standard](http://json.org/) specifies double quote characters (`"`).  I suggest that you review the documentation from the provider of this json to see if there is any way to generate correctly escaped strings, because this cannot be fixed easily on the client side without writing your own json parser.
3. The array `items` actually appears to be a polymorphic array.  The first entry looks to be information about a user of the service; subsequent entries look to be information about songs.  Maybe this is a playlist, and the first entry is the owner of the playlist?

   Anyway, you will need to filter the user information into a separate "bucket" to distinguish it from the song information.  The following class hierarchy and `JsonConverter` do the trick:

   ```
   public abstract class ResponseData
   {
       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
       public int Id { get; set; }
   }

   public class SongData : ResponseData
   {
       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "artist")]
       public string Artist { get; set; }

       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "title")]
       public string SongName { get; set; }

       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "url")]
       public string SongUri { get; set; }

       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "duration")]
       public int Duration { get; set; }

       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "owner_id")]
       public int OwnerId { get; set; }

       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "lyrics_id")]
       public int LyricsId { get; set; }

       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "genre_id")]
       public int GenreId { get; set; }
   }

   public class UserData : ResponseData
   {
       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "photo")]
       public string Photo { get; set; }

       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
       public string Name { get; set; }

       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name_gen")]
       public string NameGen { get; set; }
   }

   public class SongList
   {
       [JsonProperty(PropertyName="count")]
       public int Count { get; set; }

       [JsonIgnore]
       public List<SongData> Songs { get; set; }

       [JsonIgnore]
       public List<UserData> Users { get; set; }

       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "items")]
       public ResponseData [] Items
       {
           get
           {
               return (Users ?? Enumerable.Empty<UserData>()).Cast<ResponseData>().Concat((Songs ?? Enumerable.Empty<SongData>()).Cast<ResponseData>()).ToArray();
           }
           set
           {
               Songs = (value ?? Enumerable.Empty<ResponseData>()).OfType<SongData>().ToList();
               Users = (value ?? Enumerable.Empty<ResponseData>()).OfType<UserData>().ToList();
           }
       }
   }

   public class ResponseDataConverter : JsonConverter
   {
       public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
       {
           return typeof(ResponseData).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
       }

       public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader,
           Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
       {
           JObject item = JObject.Load(reader);
           if (item["name"] != null)
           {
               return item.ToObject<UserData>();
           }
           else
           {
               return item.ToObject<SongData>();
           }
       }

       public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer,
           object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
       {
           throw new NotImplementedException();
       }
   }
   ```

   Note that, for clarity, I renamed some of your classes and properties and moved nested classes out of their containers.
4. Your json contains an extra level of indirection with a field `response`:

   ```
   {
       response: {
       }
   }
   ```

   This doesn't seem to add any value, so you need to extract the useful data out of this wrapper.

Putting all of the above together, the following extracts a `List<SongData>` and `List<UserData>` from this response *assuming the quoting problem is fixed*:

```
        var json = e.Result;
        var jobject = ParseWithMissingBraces(json);

        var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        serializer.Converters.Add(new ResponseDataConverter());
        var songList = jobject["response"].ToObject<SongList>(serializer);

        var songs = songList.Songs;
        var users = songList.Users;
```

Comment: Thank you! For me you like a superman! Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Your class for representing your JSON structure is not correct. Remember that every json object needs to be mapped to a c# object.

This structure represents your json best, you missed the root object and Response object. I added those.

```
public class SongRoot
{
     public SongResponse response {get;set;} // maps to { response: { ...  }}
}

public class SongResponse {
     public  int count {get;set;}  // maps to count: 529
     public List<SongData2> items {get;set;}  // maps to items: [{ ... }]
}

public class SongData2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }  // maps to id: '34',
    public string Artist { get; set; } // maps to artist: 'Ocean Jet', 
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "title")]
    public string SongName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "url")]
    public string SongUri { get; set; }
    public int Duration { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "owner_id")]
    public int OwnerId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "lyrics_id")]
    public int LyricsId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "genre_id")]
    public int GenreId { get; set; }
}
```

To serialize your JSON string I used the following line:

```
var root = (SongRoot) JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SongRoot>(e.Result);
```

Which gives me in `root` an instance of `SongRoot` and `root.response.items` would give you access to the 4 `SongData` classes.

Do notice that I had to add a starting `{` and ending `}` to your JSON because otherwise it wouldn't be valid.